# Questions about API

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Link to ros API](http://wiki.ros.org/APIs)

Q1:
Why does API split into 3 parts, ROS, C++, Python respectively?

Q2:
Why some of them are identical in the same row, while others different?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248657/questions-about-api/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, you basically copied the answer in here as well :-)

> **ROS**: functionality available via ROS
> topics and services
>
> **C++**:
> functionality available in C++
> libraries
>
> **Python**: functionality
> available in Python modules/packages

ROS has client libraries, `roscpp` and `rospy` that allow you to use ROS functionalities in C++ and Python code, respectively.

So, you have a [C++ API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)), to e.g. use Publishers and Subscribers, as well as a [Python API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29). Those two are obviously different.
From the outside, a topic looks, however, the same, wether it comes from a python or a C++ node. You can manipulate this e.g. using the `topic_tools` package, which are just ROS nodes written in either C++ or python.

However, this is only a very rough overview, don't get stuck too much on this list.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-23**:
I thought those 3 lines roughly are my answer, yet I confused, so I post it to look for a clear explanation.

Thanks for your patient and clear reply, it helps!